# Identifiying 'Transferred' calls on MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm using MS Teams OpenGraph API to fetch CDR details (ref API: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/{callDataRecordId}?$expand=sessions($expand=segments)`)

It seems to be I'm totally unable to distinguish regular 1-to-1 calls from transferred calls or figuring the path of a call.

The only thing that I can tell from the CDR data is the `failureInfo` which seems *sometimes* is:

```
failreInfo {
   stage: callSetup
   reason: Other
}
```

[Update]

The scenario I'm trying to make:

1. MS User calls a phone number.
2. MS User puts call on hold. [15 seconds]
3. MS User resumes call.
4. MS User transfers call to another MS Teams account.
5. The other MS Teams account picks up for few seconds and then closes the phone.

An illustrated path: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B264d.png]

Comment: What callRecordId you are passing? A call record id will be generated once the call is completed. FailureInfo shows when a call or portion of call is failed

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Hi. Thanks for replying! If the call is transferred, is it marked as failed? I've ran two test scenarios and in both cases the call had 'failureInfo' before being transferred. I'll attach a diagram to the OP.

Comment: There is no way to identify transferred calls right now, We have a backlog item for this